# Custom loss for single-label, multi-class problem

Tags: pytorch, classification, loss-function, cross-entropy

I have a single-label, multi-class classification problem, i.e., a given sample is in exactly one class (say, class 3), but for training purposes, predicting class 2 or 5 is still okay to not penalise the model that heavily.

For example, the ground truth for 1 sample is [0,1,1,0,1] of 5 classes, instead of a one-hot vector. This implies that, the model predicting **any one** (not necessarily all) of the above classes (2,3 or 5) is fine.

For every batch, the predicted output dimension is of the shape `bs x n x nc`, where bs is the batch size, n is the number of samples per point and nc is the number of classes. The ground truth is also of the same shape as the predicted tensor.

For every batch, I'm expecting my loss function to compare `n` tensors across `nc` classes and then average it across `n`.

Eg: When dimensions are 32 x 8 x 5000. There are 32 *batch points* in a batch (for bs=32). Each batch point has 8 *vector points*, and each vector point has 5000 classes. For a given batch point, I wish to compute loss across all (8) *vector points*, compute their average and do so for the rest of the *batch points* (32). Final loss would be loss over all losses from each *batch point*.

How can I approach designing such a loss function? Any help would be deeply appreciated

P.S.: Let me know if the question is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this was to use a sigmoid function on the network output, which removes the implicit interdependency between class scores that a softmax function has.

As for the loss function, you can then calculate the loss based on the *highest* prediction for any of your target classes and ignore all other class predictions. For your example:

```py
# your model output
y_out = torch.tensor([[0.1, 0.2, 0.95, 0.1, 0.01]], requires_grad=True)
# class labels
y = torch.tensor([[0,1,1,0,1]])
```

since we only care about the *highest* class probability, we set all other class scores to the maximum value achieved for one of the classes:

```py
class_mask = y == 1
max_class_score = torch.max(y_out[class_mask])
y_hat = torch.where(class_mask, max_class_score, y_out)
```

From which we can use a regular Cross-Entropy loss function

```py
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y.float())
loss.backward()
```

when inspecting the gradients, we see that this *only* updates the prediction that achieved the highest score as well ass all predictions outside of any of the classes.

```py
>>> y_out.grad
tensor([[ 0.3326,  0.0000, -0.6653,  0.3326,  0.0000]])
```

Predictions for other target classes do not receive a gradient update. Note that if you have a very high ratio of possible classes, this might slow down your convergence.